# Android: How make SPI communication with a microSD card

Tags: android, sd-card, spi

I am programming in Android 2.3.3 (Java) on a Galaxy S (from Samsung). I would like to use a microSD card as a GPIO port, to communicate in SPI with a device.

Which library need I use to perform this task? How do I perform SPI communication (Now I use classical SPI communication with a microcontroller and Android language (simple applications)). Is it possible to do this?
How do I read values from SD card pin (how to declare them)?

Comment: That does not sound possible unless you write your own kernel driver in a custom firmware.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to look at the lowest driver level in the existing kernel.  Two problems you may face are that the sd card is almost certainly not being run in the slow SPI mode by the existing driver, and that you may not be able to obtain a full data sheet for the processor in order to figure out how to use those pins as GPIOs or with a simple SPI engine rather than the faster SD-spec mode being used.  You'd probably have more luck with the USB connector.

Comment: Thanks for yours precisions. However, I would not manage a SD card memory but I just want to use SD card pins as a mine to connect a device which can be controlled by SPI protocol. There is an android.net.spi class. ?

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing a kernel module, you will have to use the Android GPIO library to bit bang SPI on GPIOs. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio .